# Download file behind Integrated Windows Auth from command line

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, ntlm, windows-authentication

I'm looking for a way to be able to download the contents of a particular url that's protected behind Integrated Windows authentication from a computer that is a member of the domain, using the computer's domain account credentials.

From what I can see, if I browse to the file from internet explorer, I'm automatically 'logged in' with my current domain account, and receive the file back. Is there a way of carrying out the same process from a script and saving the contents to disk?

My initial thought was `wget` for windows, but looking closer led me to believe that while it supported NTLM auth, you had to put the credentials in as arguments which is something I want to avoid. Ideally, I'd like a command-line version of IE where I can just provide the url and the destination and have it use the executing process's domain account to automatically log in and download the file.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Have you investigated BITS?  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819413.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753856%28WS.10%29.aspx